# Отключить disabled в js

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такой js-код

```
  document.getElementById('value_textarea').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  document.getElementById('value_input').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled'); 
   $('#js-type').on('change', function() {
  var selection = $(this).val();

  $('div#values > div').hide();
  $("#"+selection).show();
```

Что он делает - есть форма , первое поле - `select`, второе - поле ввода. Есть 2 типа `input` и `textarea`. Изначально поля `display:none` и `disabled`. Мне нужно, чтобы при отображении нужного поля(в зависимости от выбранного в `selecte`) атрибут `disable` убирался.
Как это сделать?

---

Код dropdown (вместо selecta)

```
   <?= $form->field($model, 'type')->dropDownList(['input' => 'Input', 'image' => 'Image',
                        'textarea' => 'TextArea',
                        'fck' => 'FCK Editor',
                        'checkbox' => 'CheckBox',
                    ],
                        ['id' => 'js-type']);
                    ?>
```

Код нужных инпутов

```
<div id="values">
                            <div id="input" style="display:none;" >
                                <?=  $form->field($model, 'value', ['enableClientValidation' => false])->textInput(); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div id="image" style="display:none;">
                                <?= $form->field($model, 'file', ['enableClientValidation' => false])->widget(FileInput::className(), [
                                    'options'=>['accept'=>'image/*'],
                                    'pluginOptions'=>['allowedFileExtensions'=>['jpg','gif','png'],
                                    ]])->label('Изображение');
                                ?>
                            </div>
                            <div id="textarea" style="display:none;" >
                                <?=  $form->field($model, 'value', ['enableClientValidation' => false])->textarea(['rows'=>'6']); ?>
                            </div>
                    </div>
```

И js код, вот такой набросал

```
$('#values *').prop('disabled',true);
   $('#js-type').on('change', function() {
  var selection = $(this).val();
  $('div#values > div').hide();

  $("#"+selection).show();
```

Теперь тут как-то отключить didsbled надо, вот так пытался после

```
$("#"+selection).show(); 
  $("#"+selection).prop('disabled',true);
```

Но не пойму, почему не работает? Если прописать конкретный div_id то работает, а вот так по аналогии с .show нет

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#values > div > *').prop('disabled',true);
   $('#js-type').on('change', function() {
  var selection = $(this).val();
  $('div#values > div').hide();

  $("#"+selection).show();
  $("#"+selection+" > *").prop('disabled',false);
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<select id="js-type">
 <option disabled selected>select</option>
 <option value="input">Input</option>
 <option value="image">Image</option>
 <option value="textarea">TextArea</option>
</select>
<div id="values">
 <div id="input" style="display:none;" >
     <input type="text">
 </div>
 <div id="image" style="display:none;">
     <input type="file">
 </div>
 <div id="textarea" style="display:none;" >
     <textarea></textarea>
 </div>
</div>
```